# Do something if e.target is not child of xxx

Tags: jquery

I want to do change the z-index of an element when the user hover it, and reinitialize it when the user mouseout.

But my problem is that I can't find how to know when the user is hovering a child of my element to hover, or if he's leaving the element.

I tried that:

```
    var controlsWrapper = $('#controls-wrapper');

controlsWrapper.on('mouseover', function() {
    console.log('in');          
})
controlsWrapper.on('mouseout', function(e) {
    if(!controlsWrapper.has(e.target)) {
        console.log('out');
    }
})
```

Comment: use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` - that way you don't need to check if the event target is a child element, it just fires once.

Comment: use `if (controlsWrapper.has(e.target).length == 0) {` instead

Comment: or just use CSS may be? `#elem:hover { z-index: 100 }`

Comment: I don't understand you question, completely.